docker compose volumes for a nextjs project does not appear in the host
My intention is to allow people to work in the project only using Docker (and compose) if they don't want to install node locally. Also all the deps must be installed and updated using Docker. My purpose is not to have a container running with fixed deps, the project will grow and will need more deps and update them.
To test everything works I initially removed node_modules from the root project, but when the image is built and the container up and running, I don't see the node_modules folder in my project folder.
If I access to the container I can see the node_modules folder with all the deps installed, and the app is running correctly.
This is what I have in Dockerfile (I omitted the production stage as is not involved in dev process):
FROM node:20.13-alpine AS base
### END BASE ###

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
### END DEPS ###

FROM deps as development
WORKDIR /app

# needed to execute husky
RUN apk update && apk add git
RUN npm run prepare

CMD npm run dev
### END DEVELOPMENT ###

And this is the docker-compose.yml file
version: "3.8"
services:
  next-app:
    container_name: habitissimo-next-app
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules

I added the anon volume /app/node_modules to protect it from the host with the intention to execute any npm command from the container.
Also, setting this way prevents host to override the container's node_modules. This is something I found when the volume was - ./node_modules:/app/node_modules. When building the image the node_modules folder has all the deps inside of it but when the container is up and the volumes sets  I found node_modules empty causing the container exit with error because next  command was not found.
Edit: as requested this is the package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build --debug",
    "build:analyze": "ANALYZE_BUNDLE=true next build",
    "server": "node .next/standalone/server.js",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint:css": "stylelint 'src/**/*.css' --fix",
    "prepare": "husky"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "next": "14.1.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "7.48.2",
    "sharp": "0.32.6",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^14.2.3",
    "@types/node": "20.11.17",
    "@types/react": "18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.19",
    "eslint": "8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.1.3",
    "husky": "9.0.10",
    "lint-staged": "15.2.2",
    "prettier": "3.2.5",
    "stylelint": "16.2.1",
    "stylelint-config-css-modules": "4.4.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "36.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.css": [
      "stylelint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}


can you share your package.json where you have defined npm run dev? if it calls next ... can you append it with npx like npx next ... and then try

can you try to replace "dev": "next dev", with "dev": "npx next dev" and try

Which is the purpose to try npx next dev? I don't have a problem with the command itself. The problem is not having node_modules initialized after running un the container.

You can't directly see the contents of Docker named and anonymous volumes from the host.  In the setup you show:

The host system will have a node_modules directory, but its contents are ignored.  (Docker will create an empty node_modules directory if one doesn't exist.)
Neither the source code nor the node_modules directory in the image are used at all, except for the very first time you launch the container.
The actual library tree is in a Docker anonymous volume (the same as a named volume except it doesn't have a name), the contents of the volume survive across recreating the container, the contents of the volume override what's in the image, and you can't directly see the volume content.

There are hacks involving docker inspect and maybe getting a shell inside a VM that would let you see the content.
In the setup you show, you need to run all basic commands indirectly via Docker, like
docker compose run next-app npm install typescript

and you can use this same approach to see what's in the container with its mounted filesystems
docker compose run next-app ls node_modules


Totally agree. I found that running first a compose command to install deps and then run the container fixes the issue. I was going to post an answer with it until I read yours.
Thanks for clarifying the concept :D
